# Google play android market publish and save buttons have no effect

Tags: google-play, apk

**The 'android developer console' publish and save buttons don't do anything**

In the android developer console at [play.google.com/apps/publish](http://play.google.com/apps/publish), I login and click the "APK Files" tab and upload my updated APK.  I have done this successfully 15 times before.  I press the save button, literally nothing happens.  No error, no message, no page refresh, nada.  When I press the "Un-publish" button, nothing happens.  I've triple checked my program, it is working perfectly.  I've tried other browsers, restarted eclipse, the smartphone, computer, it's all fine.

Something is wrong with Android market console.  The android APK save button doesn't work.

**OK I figured out my problem.**.  I'm 100% certain it's a bug in the android developer console / Android market console.

Basically what happened is the exchange rate in Zimbabwe, Quatar and Togo and a few other places changed their exchange rates due to inflation or whatever, and when I uploaded my new APK, google needed me to review and change the prices for these countries.  So to fix here is what I have to do:

1. Go to play.google.com/apps/publish
2. Login, click your program in the android app listings, click "Upload APK tab".
3. Upload your APK.
4. Click the save and publish buttons, which are completely ineffective.
5. Click the greyed out tab: "Product Details".
6. Scroll 3/4 the way down to the exchange rate section, there is a red box around some countries.
7. Enter in a price for those countries, fix any other red items.  Click on the checkmarks at the bottom to re-validate the stuff you've validated before.
8. Go back to the upload APK tab.  Click Save.  The save produces the expected result "save completed".

Recommendation for the Google: Pushing the save button should produce a popup: "You need to review some currency exchange problems in the program details".

Comment: My saviour :).  I would also note that even on the 'Product Details' tab there should be an error message at the top of the screen.   Poor stuff, Google!  I want that hour of my life back!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you uploaded a new app version and can't save it, I think there is an error on the "Product details" tab.

Since Google Play added some new countries a few days ago, if your app is a paid one, you first have to set prices for these new countries before you can save your app.

I think it's not a real bug. There is just an error message missing on the APK tab.

Answer (score 0):

There is a real bug, but I'm not sure what it is. I had the same problem. Closing the browser tab and reopening it fixed the problem for me, showing that there was no real issue with my app settings.